# Why my WordPress plugin is not assigning thumbnail to post using set_post_thumbnail?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a WordPress plugin that will accept a CSV file with two fields. One is a post ID and the other is an image URL (ex.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ8oJ.jpg).

My code is working perfectly when the image size in the URL is big. For instance, 2800x1800px. It generates all metadata information in the wp_postmeta table (_wp_attached_file, _wp_attachment_metadata and _thumbnail_id).

But when I have smaller images, for example 1080x1080px, the code won't generate all metadata fields. _wp_attached_file and _thumbnail_id won't be generated. If I assign a variable to the set_post_thumbnail call and do a var_dump, it will always return false.

Below is the function that processes the CSV file, which is part of a PHP class. Note that I'm only using this code for study purposes, so I haven't implemented nonces and other validations yet.

```
public function create_images( $csv_file ){
    // Get data from CSV file in array format
    $source = $this->get_csv( $csv_file );

    $ids = array();
    $urls = array();

    // For each line in the array (each URL)
    for ( $i=0; $i < count($source); $i++) { 
        // Getting the IDs and URL fields
        $ids[] = (int) $source[$i]['id']; 
        $urls[] = $source[$i]['url']; 

        // Where to save the file
        $path = wp_upload_dir();
        $imgpath = $path['path'];
        $image_url = $path['url'];

        foreach( $urls as $url ){
            // WordPress generates each image
            $content = file_get_contents( $url );
            wp_upload_bits( 'post-' . $ids[$i] . '.jpg', null, $content );

            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( array(
                'post_title' => 'post-' . $ids[$i],
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_parent' => $ids[$i],
                'guid' => $image_url . '/post-' . $ids[$i] . '.jpg'
            ));

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {

                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');

                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $imgpath . '/post-' . $ids[$i] . '.jpg' );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attach_data );
                set_post_thumbnail( (int) $ids[$i], $attachment_id );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Another thing I noticed is that larger images will include the field 'post-thumbnail' in _wp_attachment_metadata, but smaller images won't do it. I don't know if that is related to the issue.

Can someone please give me some advise on how to solve the issue?